# How to read an item from summary in R

Tags: r, summary

I am using Aparch/Garch model (library: "fGarch") and want to read (& use later) the objects like AIC, t-values of the coefficients in the summary of the model fit. How can I do this?

```
m3<-(garchFit(~arma(1,0)+aparch(1,1), cond.dist= "sged" ,data=t2, trace=FALSE))
```

summary(m3)

Title:
 GARCH Modelling

Call:

```
 garchFit(formula = ~arma(1, 0) + aparch(1, 1), data = t2, cond.dist = "sged", 
    trace = FALSE)
```

Mean and Variance Equation:

```
 data ~ arma(1, 0) + aparch(1, 1)
 [data = t2]
```

Conditional Distribution:

```
 sged 

Coefficient(s):
        mu         ar1       omega      alpha1      gamma1       beta1       delta        skew       shape  
0.00063936  0.07745422  0.00116542  0.24170185  0.19179650  0.74430731  1.11902269  1.06401615  1.23013925  

Std. Errors:
 based on Hessian 

Error Analysis:
        Estimate  Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
mu     0.0006394   0.0004789    1.335 0.181828    
ar1    0.0774542   0.0256070    3.025 0.002489 ** 
omega  0.0011654   0.0003097    3.763 0.000168 ***
alpha1 0.2417019   0.0368264    6.563 5.26e-11 ***
gamma1 0.1917965   0.0699436    2.742 0.006104 ** 
beta1  0.7443073   0.0383066   19.430  < 2e-16 ***
delta  1.1190227   0.2569665    4.355 1.33e-05 ***
skew   1.0640162   0.0295095   36.057  < 2e-16 ***
shape  1.2301392   0.0592616   20.758  < 2e-16 ***

Information Criterion Statistics:
      AIC       BIC       SIC      HQIC 
-4.835325 -4.803583 -4.835395 -4.823503
```

---

Comment: your best bet is to use `ss <- summary(m3); str(ss)` to see the STRucture of the returned object and figure out how to get the pieces out (via standard R methods such as `[`, `[[`, `$`, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to extract those from the output of `garchFit`, not its summary. Start by looking at:

```
> attributes(m3)
```

Then you can access something like `$fit$tval` by doing

```
> m3@fit$tval
```